# Formatting time object specifying LC_TIME without changing locale

Tags: r, posixct

Is there a way to format a POSIXct object in R and specifying the LC_TIME in that call?

Ie I have this code which returns the object in the German format

```
t <- Sys.time()
fmt <- "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT"
format(t, fmt)
#> [1] "Mi, 23 Mrz 2022 14:57:50 GMT"

Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
#> [1] "German_Germany.1252"
```

The format I want can be achieved by setting the LC_TIME, but this is not what I want. Instead I want to find a solution without changing the options of my R session or my locale.

```r
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
format(t, fmt)
#> [1] "Wed, 23 Mar 2022 14:57:50 GMT"
# correct output, but changing the locale :(
```

Ideally, I want something like `format(t, fmt, LC_TIME = "C")` or similar with minimal external dependencies and not changing anything else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a perfect solution but there is a workaround using `local()`, depending on your purposes. `local()` let you define variables as in a function, so your global environment won't be disturbed.

```
fmt <- "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT"
local({
  locale <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
  Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
  final_date <- format(Sys.time(), fmt)
  Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", locale)
  return(final_date)})
#> [1] "Wed, 25 May 2022 12:03:36 GMT"
```

Unfortunately the system locale is changed so you should use `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", locale)` at the end to turn it back. The advantage of this method is that you can get what you want with zero changes in your variables (the variable `locale` would be created otherwise).